# ggplot2: plot mean points(and lines connecting them) of the factor by x－axis class on a boxplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to plot each mean of the factor(MAP) on each Size(x-axis), can anybody help me?

```
qplot(Size,Rc,data=rc.data, geom="boxplot") + 
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(MAP)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining means on a boxplot with a line (ggplot2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989987/joining-means-on-a-boxplot-with-a-line-ggplot2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `stat_summary` to calculate and plot the means:

```
qplot(Size,Rc,data=rc.data, geom="boxplot") + 
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(MAP))) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="line", aes(colour=factor(MAP), group=factor(MAP))) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(colour=factor(MAP), pch=3, size=3)
```