# add lines for upper/lower bond, median to ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, boxplot

I've got a boxplot like:

[image]

Which is really hard to tell which group tends to have higher values.

How do I add lines in the chart that connect Q1, Q2, Q3 for each group respectively?

Comment: `ggplot(dplyr::starwars, aes(eye_color, height, color = gender)) + geom_boxplot() + stat_summary(aes(group = gender), geom = 'line', fun.y = median)`

Comment: @alistaire [This is not an exact dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989987/joining-means-on-a-boxplot-with-a-line-ggplot2), it's not even explained why `group = 1` works. Care to post as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `stat_summary` to apply an aggregation function to each group of y values and pass the result to a geom. There's a caveat: boxplots are already grouped (each box is a group), so to get a geom to cross boxplots, you'll have to set the grouping differently between `geom_boxplot` and `stat_summary`. Think of the group aesthetic as defining what should be connected or separate.

See `?stat_summary` for the full details of how you can specify the aggregation function, but the tl;dr is that it can either take independent functions for y, ymin, and ymax, or one called `fun.data` that returns a data frame with columns named `y`, `ymin`, and `ymax`. Args can also be passed through `fun.args` if you don't want to write anonymous functions. If the geom doesn't need all three aesthetics, you can just specify one (e.g. lines just need `y`).

So to plot lines at the first, second, and third quartiles, adding some dodging so everything lines up,

```r
library(ggplot2)

data('mpg', package = 'ggplot2')
mpg$cyl <- factor(mpg$cyl)

# note grouping here is set to what stat_summary needs (so we don't have to override so many times)
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy, color = cyl, group = cyl)) +
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = NULL)) +    # override grouping here back to the default
    stat_summary(geom = 'line', fun.y = median, position = position_dodge(0.75)) + 
    stat_summary(geom = 'line', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = 0.25), position = position_dodge(0.75)) + 
    stat_summary(geom = 'line', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = 0.75), position = position_dodge(0.75))
```

[image: boxplots with lines]

This plot is pretty busy, though. Another parallel coordinates/boxplot cross might be to use `geom_ribbon` (which takes ymin and ymax) for the first and third quantiles:

```r
ggplot(mpg, aes(class, hwy, color = cyl, fill = cyl, group = cyl)) + 
    geom_boxplot(aes(group = NULL, fill = NULL)) + 
    stat_summary(geom = 'line', fun.y = median, position = position_dodge(0.75)) + 
    stat_summary(geom = 'ribbon', alpha = 0.3, position = position_dodge(0.75),
                 fun.data = function(x) {
                     data.frame(ymin = quantile(x, 0.25), 
                                ymax = quantile(x, 0.75))
                 })
```

[image: boxplots with line and ribbon]

Comment: Wow, this `geom_ribbon` looks awesome. Thanks for sharing!