# adding a dashed line to mark the mean in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to plot the following data frame as a boxplot:

```
df <- structure(list(gender = c("M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M"), age = c(0.047843262001096, 
-0.742811587141869, 0.925285031087175, 0.0921270156895479, -0.869460001218705, 
-0.468079587412729, -0.480948831743091, 0.879330955606316, -0.249821527515907, 
0.386670185484268, 0.670264658324484, 0.382273448950274, 0.0500787926732772, 
2.39384630378084, 0.862479212110272)), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to replace the point with a horizontal dashed line:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age)) + geom_boxplot() + 
stat_summary(fun.data = mean_sdl, geom = "point", color = "red")
```

I have tried "line" instead of "point" but doesnt seem to produce anything.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want such a line? You can try `geom_hline()`..Can't test, no access to R.

Comment: I want to mark the mean which can be very different from the median. geom_hline doesn't fit the syntax here.

Comment: What do you mean `geom_hline` doesn't fit the syntax? You can feed the data via `aes`..However, there must be a better and more conventional way to present your data. Can't get what you mean by mean being different from the median and how that relates to `geom_hline`. Could you add a sample of your expected plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Joining means on a boxplot with a line (ggplot2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989987/joining-means-on-a-boxplot-with-a-line-ggplot2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `stat_summary` use the `Mean` function shown below with the `boxplot` geom. Also set `width` to ensure that both geoms have the same width.

```
Mean <-  function(x) {
  setNames(rep(mean(x), 5), c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax"))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age, width = 0.75)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   stat_summary(fun.data = Mean, geom = "boxplot", linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

ADDED:

In his answer, @caldwellst shows that the `errorbar` geom could be used and that would also work in the code above by simply replacing  `geom="boxplot"` with `geom="errorbar"` in `stat_summary`.  That does have the advantage over `geom="boxplot"` of producing nicer looking dashed lines.

Although `Mean` as defined above would work as is with `errorbar` we really only need the `ymin` and `ymax` components that `Mean` above outputs so we could reduce it as shown:

```
Mean <- function(x) c(ymin = mean(x), ymax = mean(x))

ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age, width = 0.75)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   stat_summary(fun.data = Mean, geom = "errorbar", linetype = "dashed")
```

This could also be written like this replacing `Mean` with the indicated formula which `fn$` from gsubfn will convert to a function whose body is the right hand side of the formula.

```
library(gsubfn)

ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age, width = 0.75)) +
   geom_boxplot() +
   fn$stat_summary(fun.data = ~ c(ymin = mean(x), ymax = mean(x)), 
     geom = "errorbar", linetype = "dashed")
```

Answer (score 3):

Edited based on comment and used entirely with stat_summary if so desired. Can also use `fun.data` if desired.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age, yintercept = mean(age)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, color = "yellow", size = 3, geom = "hline", linetype = 2)
```

Since you've shown you want the line for each boxplot, you can do the below entirely within ggplot without the need of defining an additional function.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = gender, y = age, width = 0.75)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "errorbar", aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..), linetype = 2)
```

[image: graph example with mean dashes]

Comment: Better not to use `$` in `ggplot2`: Try: `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(age)), linetype =2)`..Might lead to different results especially for grouped data.

Answer (score 3):

You could use base `boxplot()` and `arrows()` with `length=0` of the arrow heads. The boxes' borders appear to be in `.4` distance from the centers. To get the `mean`s use `aggregate()`.

```
df <- as.data.frame(df)
boxplot(age ~ gender, df)
a <- aggregate(age ~ gender, df, mean)
arrows(1 - .4, a[1, 2], 1 + .4, length=0, lty=2, lwd=2, col=2)
arrows(2 - .4, a[2, 2], 2 + .4, length=0, lty=2, lwd=2, col=2)
```

[image]